# Manage routing in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Have a problem with routing in Yii2. I have controller action name in camelcase, a url-manager rule using UrlRule class for this controller.

Action:

```
public function actionCreateRole()
{
    if (!isset($_POST['name'])) {
        throw new BadRequestHttpException("Не передан обязательный параметр 'name'");
    }

    $name = $_POST['name'];

    if ($this->getAuthManager()->getRole($name) !== null) {
        throw new BadRequestHttpException("Роль уже существует");
    }

    $role = $this->getAuthManager()->createRole($name);
    $role->description = $_POST['description'];
    if (!$this->getAuthManager()->add($role)) {
        throw new ServerErrorHttpException();
    }

    return $role;
}
```

UrlManager config:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'controller' => [
                'rbac',
            ],
            'patterns'=>[
                'POST role' => 'create-role',
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

On request have 404 error.

I'm try set patterns to:

```
'patterns'=>[
     'POST role' => 'createRole',
],
```

Response - error 404.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: What's the controller's name?

Comment: What is the path or your url ? You may have an issue with the pluralize rule (which defaults to `true`). You url should be something like `POST /rbacs` and your controller should be `RbacController`.

Comment: Mat, Thank you, problem was in pluralize attribute